# Error when using QRGen library to generate QR code

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, noclassdeffounderror

I am using the QRGen library to generate a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for a QR code and the generate a Bitmap image for it.

I have imported the 3 following jars into my project:

- qrgen-1.0.jar
- zxing-core-1.7.jar
- zxing-j2se-1.7.jar

This is the method generating the QR code ByteArray:

```
public Bitmap qrBitmapFromString(String qrText){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(qrText).to(ImageType.PNG).withSize(300, 300).stream();
    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (data,0,data.length, null);
    return bmp;
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(MatrixToImageWriter.java:48)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(MatrixToImageWriter.java:75)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode.stream(QRCode.java:99)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at co.emuze.emuzepay.PayCardFragment.qrBitmapFromString(PayCardFragment.java:27)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at co.emuze.emuzepay.PayCardFragment.onCreateView(PayCardFragment.java:23)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:795)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-05 12:39:31.089: E/AndroidRuntime(1479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can cause that?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace answers your question. `java.awt` classes don't exist in Android. You can't use libraries that use AWT. You can't use QRGen, or at least not this part of it.

Comment: is there a way to import that class to android?

Comment: No. AWT is Java's desktop application and has no place on Android. Use zxing directly, which supports Android. You just can't use the bits in `javase/`

Answer (score 0):

2.0-SNAPSHOT should solve this https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/glxn/qrgen/android/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

Answer (score 0):

2.0-SNAPSHOT works very well on android and has become faster during the last week. An example can be found here: https://github.com/atomfrede/qrgen-android-example