# Android: Error when using QRGen lib to generate QR code

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to generate QRCode image using `QRGen library`.

I have imported `qrgen-1.0.jar` file to my project.

I know this question is duplicate. 
I have referred following code by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221775/error-when-using-qrgen-library-to-generate-qr-code)

```
public Bitmap qrBitmapFromString(String qrText){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(qrText).to(ImageType.PNG).withSize(300, 300).stream();
    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (data,0,data.length, null);
    return bmp; 
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:           net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.example.barcodeexample.QRCodeGeneratorActivity.onCreate(QRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:34)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 11:48:57.138: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have imported

```
import net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode;
import net.glxn.qrgen.image.ImageType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found and following thing working well for me.

1. Right click on your project
2. Go into Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Go to Order and Export
5. Check your OnBarcode library
6. Clean your project

Think this may help some one like me.

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't found Build path on right click on project. Using Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

2.0-SNAPSHOT should solve this https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/glxn/qrgen/android/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen